# Create a copy or use reference for parameter?

Tags: c++

My problem is that I want to return a common substring of two strings s1, s2. Apparently, s1 and s2 are symmetric.

```
string shortest_common( const string& s1, const string& s2 ) {

}
```

There are three possible solutions to this problem that I came up with:

- Either make a copy of s1 and s2
- Or swap them, which means I have to sacrifice their const-ness
- Or worst, duplicate code!

I personally prefer the first case, since intent is to find the shortest-common string not changing s1 or s2. So my question is: Which option is ideal in this case?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: They're symmetrical meaning palindromic? As in, 'abba' and 'cabbac' are valid input and 'abba' would be the result?

Comment: Wait, shortest common string? That's  not even itneresting as the answer is always "" :)

Comment: @Matt Kane: It's a modified version, not a traditionally palindromic. It has many sub-cases that I have to handle.

Comment: Matt is correct.  You would need it to be shortest common substring with a minimum length.  Anything less than 2 would give you a lot of results for any non-trivial pair of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt to go with the signature that you've displayed.  If you're finding a common substring then you don't want to have side-effects.  That's not what people think of when they would call your function.  I don't expect a function called "add_two_numbers" to modify one of the numbers and return a value.

Comment: Your thought matched mine ;). I will go for this option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to swap the meanings of parameters without changing the objects themselves in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what your actual question is, so I'll judge by the title.

Do both:

```
void shortest_common( string& s1, const string& s2 )
{
  // real algorithm changing s1
}

inline string shortest_common( string s1, const string& s2 )
{
  shortest_common( s1, s2 );
  return s1;
}
```

Comment: @sbi: If you're just going to copy the parameter, isn't it better to use pass by value to make the copy?  I thought that opens up some additional optimizations (and of course in C++0x, the "real implementation would use an rvalue-reference, and the forwarder would use `std::move`)

Comment: @Ben: I'm using VC++ 2010. According to what you mentioned, is passing `std::string` by copy even better?

Comment: @Chan: Usually you pass class object per `const` reference, __unless__ you need a copy of the parameter within the function anyway. (See [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254)) The reason is that the compiler might be able to elide the copying when you pass an rvalue (a temporary object) as this parameter.

Comment: @Chan: In VC2010, the first function (the real implementation) would be `string shortest_common( string&& s1, const string& s2 )`, and the forwarder than doesn't eat its first argument `inline string shortest_common( string s1, const string& s2 ) { return shortest_common(std::move(s1), s2); }`.